# Access SAP HANA monitoring data

Tags: hana

I want to write a Java program where I need to monitor the SAP HANA.

Can someone please let me know is there any client library or Java SDK or REST API available to get all the metrics data for all monitors provided by SAP HANA?

Answer (score 0):

I did some googling for you but found nothing. 
However, I saw it in action somewhere in the system, so in case no one will be able to help you here, you will find an answer on SCN.

As, I had an experience of doing exactly this, I would say that writing the stuff on your own with xsjs will not be a big issue and will not be too different from [this](http://saphanatutorial.com/sap-hana-xsjs-database-connectivity/) tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much for your information.. Can you please let me know is there any possibility that I can get the monitoring data through any tables? I guess the monitoring data is stored in some table may be some system table. Where can I get the table information? I am new to this so trying to capture the information..

Comment: You probably need to start [here](https://help.sap.com/hana_one/html/monitor_views.html)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the monitoring information can be read from the statistics server tables [see docu here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/21/00370d751910149a5abe63e752dae0/content.htm).